# Debian Router : Allow Incoming traffic from intranet

Tags: networking, router, debian

i have school network `10.0.0.0/8`

i have debian running with static assigned IP `10.122.72.2` gateway `10.122.72.1` on eth0 and local network `10.122.2.0/24` on eth1

The problem is i can access others network, eg. `10.122.1.0/24` but i can't access my local network from outside, eg. `ping 10.122.2.1` from `10.122.1.0/24` network

`tracert 10.122.1.1` from my local network give me how the packet was routed `10.122.2.1 -> 10.122.72.1 -> 10.122.1.1`

And `tracert 10.122.2.1` from `10.122.1.0/24` network give me `10.122.1.1 -> 10.122.254.9 -> request timed out`

`sudo route -n` give me this :

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination Gateway     Genmask       Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
0.0.0.0     10.122.72.1 0.0.0.0       UG    0      0   0   eth0
10.122.2.0  0.0.0.0     255.255.255.0 U     0      0   0   eth1
10.122.72.0 0.0.0.0     255.255.255.0 U     0      0   0   eth0
```

and here is my `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.122.72.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.122.72.0
broadcast 10.122.72.255
gateway 10.122.72.1
# dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
dns-nameservers 202.46.129.2
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 10.122.2.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.122.2.0
broadcast 10.122.2.255
```

Here is my firewall rules

```
outif="eth0"
lanif="eth1"
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $lanif -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $outif -j MASQUERADE
```

How can i make my local network accessible from outside?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not your router (at least not yet).

The `tracert` you ran shows that `10.122.254.9` does not seem to know where to route the packet next. You need to configure the other routers in the school network to route `10.122.2.0/24` to your router.

Once that is done you should even be able to remove NAT from your router.

Given the two `tracert` results you have given, it seems your network is something like this : [image: Network representation]

IP routing works hop by hop. When you try sending a packet to `10.122.2.1`, there are two possibilities:

1. You are on the same subnet as `10.122.2.1`: You simply find out its layer 2 address and send it the packet.
2. You are on a different subnet. You look up your routing table to find a router on your subnet that will get you closer to `10.122.2.1`, find its layer 2 address and send him the packet. He then follows the samee steps you did.

In your case, when you are on the `10.122.1.0/24` network, if the representation given above is correct, you can send a message to the school controlled routers 1 and 2 (2 being the default gateway, when you don't know who to send it to).

Since you are not on the `10.122.2.0/24` network, and you don't know who to send it to, you send it to the default gateway, `10.122.1.1` aka School controlled router 2. It isn't on the same subnet as `10.122.2.1` either, and doesn't have a special entry for it so sends it to it's default gateway, `10.122.254.9`, which in turn probably tries to send it to the internet, at which point it is dropped as it `10.122.2.1` is in a private IP range.

If you are on the `10.122.72.0/24` network you could add an entry to tell your computer that `10.122.2.0/24` is accessible through `10.122.72.2`, but as you are on yet another subnet, you need to tell the school controlled routers that `10.122.2.0/24` is accessible through `10.122.72.2`. In this case it would mean updating school controlled router 1 with a direct entry for your network as being accessible through your Debian machine, and school controlled router 2 with an entry for your netwok as being accessible through school controlled router 1.

Without controlling the school routers, this is not something you can do. The best you can do, is set up a VPN server on your Debian machine, and then tunnel traffic to `10.122.2.0/24` using a VPN connection.

Comment: @Matthew: Thanks for reply. But is it possible to just use ip route command? Because, all of `10.0.0.0/8` subnets can accesss `10.122.1.0/24` network without having to configure anything. As info, i can access `10.122.72.2` and `10.122.72.1` from all of `10.0.0.0/8` subnets. So again, is it possible to just route the traffic, something like `ip route add -net 10.122.2.0/24 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.122.72.2`. i just tried this with no success. Thanks

Comment: @user2313067: i'm sorry for inconvenience and thanks for reply.But is it possible to just use ip route command? Because, all of `10.0.0.0/8` subnets can accesss `10.122.1.0/24` network without having to configure anything. As info, i can access `10.122.72.2` and `10.122.72.1` from all of `10.0.0.0/8` subnets. So again, is it possible to just route the traffic, something like `ip route add -net 10.122.2.0/24 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.122.72.2`. i just tried this with no success. Thanks

Comment: @user310055 Do you have the tracert after you have added that route? (By the way `/24` and `mask 255.255.255.0` are redundant. In this case they mean the same thing, but I don't know which one would prevail should they be different. Better enter only one of them)

Comment: @user310055 I edited my reply with how I think your network setup is and why you cannot access `10.122.2.0/24` without updating the school routers' configuration.

Comment: i'm sorry my class recently was renovated, so i can't go to my class since then. here is my school's network configuration http://i.imgur.com/YJkWGEq.png